# Set up angular 2 Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular, gulp, asp.net-core

I have been trying for days to get my project set up correctly. I am going from this post [here](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/)

I have everything working but when I want to put my view in an .html file instead of inline I am having trouble getting the folder structure and html files in the wwwroot folder so I can correctly map my templateUrl's.

So my questions are:
Is it possible to put the scripts folder and my angular app files inside the wwwroot folder instead of in the root of my project?

If not, how do I get gulp to move my compiled .ts files and my folder structure and html to the wwwroot folder?

My current folder structure is something like this
http://screencast.com/t/DAk3yEBu0X3b

I do not know how to reference my app.html since it does not get moved into wwwroot file.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I am trying to use Steve Sanderson's Template, the one @Mike Mazmanyan suggested.
The template is making me even more confused. It looks like its using CommonJS to compile the templates and put them in the script file instead of just referencing them from the server.

Is the the preferred way to write angular applications? 
It seams like if you put your whole application including html in one script file it will take a long time to download.

Is it possible to do both?
Put some templates in a script file and have some that are just a path to a endpoint? I want to use the server side partial templates like in the [post](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommonJS module format to load .html templates into your components.

I will suggest to use [Steve Sanderson's Template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/) for Angular 2. He is using WebPack for bundling all typescript, css, etc.

Comment: When I compile Steve Sanderson's template it puts the angular templates inside the compiled javascript file instead of just referencing the html file on the server. Is this the way angular 2 is supposed to behave? It seams like if you put all you html for a large project inside a script file it will end up being to big to download.